# Switch (Thumb and Track) Android

Tags: java, android, xml

guys! I have a question :) trying to customize a switch a little bit, such as the outline of the switch will have a border, and the inside part of it, the one you click to activate the event, also with a border, but in a way that it won't overlap the outline border of the switch. Since I don't have enough rep, I can't actually post the picture, therefore I hope it is clear enough :) what I got so far is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="50dp"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="3dp"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/wampRed"/>

</shape>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/wampRed"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"/>


</shape>
```

<

```
Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switchButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:textOn=""
        android:thumb="@drawable/shape_track"
        android:track="@drawable/shape_thumb"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textOff="       "
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateOutput"

        />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make the thumb be smaller than the track, and both have outlines, you should create two custom drawables for each. The thumb drawable should be "layer-list" so that you can add padding around the thumb to make it not overlap the track.

For example for thumb:

```
<layer-list>
    <item 
        android:top="@dimen/thumb_padding"
        android:left="@dimen/thumb_padding"
        android:right="@dimen/thumb_padding"
        android:bottom="@dimen/thumb_padding">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/your_color"/>
            <size
                android:height="@dimen/thumb_diameter"
                android:width="@dimen/thumb_diameter"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
 </layer-list>
```

and for track:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/track_radius" />
            <size 
              android:height="@dimen/switch_height"
              android:width="@dimen/switch_width"/>
            <stroke
              android:width="@dimen/your_outline_thickness"
              android:color="@color/your_color"/>
        </shape>
```

Lmk if you meant something different I'll try to edit quickly